# How can I have a keypress do one thing the first time, and a different thing the second time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, keypress, osc

So I've put this script together, which allows me to send an osc, (open sound control), message whenever I hit the "w" key. (I need this to run in the background of my computer so any suggestions on how to make it more efficient would be appreciated!! :D)

The problem I've come to, is that I want it to send a different message when I hit "w" for the second time. (That's where the `client.send_message` comes in.) You'll see that I began to write this, to no avail lol.

In a nutshell, when I hit "w" the first time, it works perfectly. (Executes `client.send_message("/TABS", "Mixer")`). Now when I hit it the second time, I want it to execute `client.send_message("/TABS", "Instruments")` How can I go about doing this?

Code:

```
import argparse
import pynput

from pythonosc import udp_client
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput import keyboard
import keyboard

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", default="192.168.1.140",
        help="The ip of the OSC server")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=8420,
        help="The port the OSC server is listening on")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient(args.ip, args.port)

    def on_press(key):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
            client.send_message("/TABS", "Mixer")
        else:
            client.send_message("/TABS", "Instruments")


    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: Do you want the two actions to cycle back and forth with each press of "w", or do you want the "Mixer" only on the first press, and then "Instruments" on _all_ following presses?

Comment: @b_c Thanks for the reply! I'd like it to cycle back and forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to cycle the two operations back and forth, you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to do exactly that.

First, you'll want to define two small functions to do your two operations. In this case, I'm sending `client` as an argument to the functions.

```
def do_mixer(client_arg):
    client_arg.send_message("/TABS", "Mixer")

def do_instruments(client_arg):
    client_arg.send_message("/TABS", "Instruments")
```

Then, you can create a `cycle` object to endlessly switch between the two functions with each press to "w":

```
import argparse
import pynput

from pythonosc import udp_client
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput import keyboard
import keyboard

# Additional import
from itertools import cycle

# New funcs
def do_mixer(client_arg):
    client_arg.send_message("/TABS", "Mixer")

def do_instruments(client_arg):
    client_arg.send_message("/TABS", "Instruments")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", default="192.168.1.140",
        help="The ip of the OSC server")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=8420,
        help="The port the OSC server is listening on")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient(args.ip, args.port)

    # Function cycler
    func_cycler = cycle((do_mixer, do_instruments))

    def on_press(key):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
            # With each press of "w", call the function that is next in line
            # The cycle object will iterate the collection given to it infinitely
            # In this case, it will be: do_mixer, do_instruments, do_mixer, ...
            next(func_cycler)(client)

    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: So I tried adding the code you suggested, and I got a syntax error: "  File "c:\Users\john\Desktop\test1.4.pyw", line 33
    def on_press(key):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" Is there a way I can share how I copied and pasted your code in? Sorry I'm new to the forum haha

Comment: @maczook only way would be an edit to your original post

Comment: ahh :( would you mind copying and pasting your code into the spots you'd put them in, and then re- answer with that code? :D hahahaha

Comment: Check the edits - I subbed it in with some comments :)

Comment: OH MY GOD!! YOU ARE SUCH A BOSS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! :D:D:D:D